# Finding the time complexity of doing k += sqrt(k) in a loop

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

Given this code:

```c
int f(int n)
{
    int j = 10;
    while( j < n) {
        j += sqrt(j);
        printf("Hello\n");
    }
    return j;
}
```

How can I find its Time Complexity, the solution is `O(sqrt(n))` but still why?

Thank you for your time <3

What I was able to find is that the variable `j` belongs to a sequence u
<sub>n+1</sub>=u<sub>n</sub>+sqrt(u<sub>n</sub>), trying and trying to find its general term didn't lead me anywhere, I also tried using a generating function for it but still didn't work.